# Feature Toggle in Salesforce having Flows

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud, simple-salesforce

I have 2 existing flows and 16 new flows. I am trying to implement a feature toggle for these components wherein on click of a button or on toggle of something, the new versions of the old flows and the new flows need to be turned ON or OFF with that toggle switch.

A custom metadata record can be created having a flag and can maybe control the new flows but those new flows still have to be made active. The old flow's existing version cannot be modified with this new flag and it cannot turn on the new version automatically. Checking if anyone has a solution to activate or deactivate all new/old flows with a toggle.